# Curly brackets VS Code on mac Osx

Tags: visual-studio

Just moved to Mac OSX and I can't type curly brackets with the old ALT-123 for open brace and so on.
Any fast solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out but I create some snippets into the keybindings.json

```
// Empty
[    
    // INSERT CURLY BRACKETS
    {
        "key": "alt+numpad2",
        "command": "extension.embraceCurlyBrackets",
        "when": "editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus"
    },
     { 
    "key": "alt+shift+numpad2",
    "command":  "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "{\n\t$1\n}",  
    },
        "when": "editorTextFocus" 
  },
    { 
    "key": "alt+numpad1",
    "command":  "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "{$1"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus" 
  },
    { 
    "key": "alt+numpad3",
    "command":  "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "}$1"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus" 
  },
  // INSERT CONSOLE LOG
    { 
    "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
    "command":  "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "console.log($1)"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus" 
  },

 ]
```

A few shortcuts to speed up the work!